# Presenter View for Slidy?

Tags: presentations

Is there a way I can get Slidy to show me speaker notes?

I want to connect my MacBook Pro to a projector, then give a presentation in which I can see each slide as the audience sees it, in addition to seeing (on my laptop) private speaker notes to myself that the audience CANNOT see.

Is this possible with Slidy? Or should I just bite the bullet and switch to Powerpoint, which supports this?

Comment: *Slidy* as in [HTML Slidy](http://www.w3.org/2005/03/slideshow.html)?

Comment: @daniel-beck Yes, exactly, HTML Slidy. Right I'm using Pandoc to convert Markdown to HTML Slidy.

Answer (score 0):

Slidy does not support speaker notes, but [reveal.js does](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#speaker-notes):

```
<section data-markdown="example.md" data-separator="^\n\n\n" data-separator-vertical="^\n\n" data-separator-notes="^Note:"></section>

# Title
## Sub-title

Here is some content...

Note:
This will only display in the notes window.
```

Replace `-t slidy` with `-t revealjs -V revealjs-url=https://revealjs.com` in your [pandoc command](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Using-pandoc-to-produce-reveal.js-slides#creating-the-slides):

```
$ pandoc -t revealjs -V revealjs-url=https://revealjs.com -s -o slides.html slides.md
```

When presenting, hit the `S` key to open a new window with speaker notes.